# What is wrong with my Mongoose data seeding script?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to populate my MongoDB database with data via a script (JS) that I run through `npm run`.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dbConf = require('../config/database.js')

const User = require('../app/models/user.js')
const Account = require('../app/models/account.js')


mongoose.connect(dbConf.url, { useMongoClient: true })
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

const users = [
  {
    _id: "58c039018060197ca0b52d4c",
    email: "user1@example.com",
    password: "foo",
    balance_cents: 100
  },
  {
    _id: "58c03ada8060197ca0b52d52",
    email: "user2@example.com",
    password: "foo",
    balance_cents: 50000
  }
]

const accounts = [
  {
    name: "Postbank",
    iban: "1232423423",
    swift: "2444444"
  },
  {
    name: "DKB",
    iban: "1234923423",
    swift: "6667898"
  },
  {
    name: "Fidor",
    iban: "909873423",
    swift: "998733"
  }
]

async function dropDatabase () {
  console.log('Removing User collection')
  await User.remove()
  console.log('Success!')
}

async function seedUsers () {
  console.log('Seeding users..')
  try {
    await User.insertMany(users)
    console.log('Success!')
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('Error:' + e)
  }
}

dropDatabase()
seedUsers()

process.exit(0)
```

But it doesn't seem to get past the `await` statements in each function. The output is:

```
Removing User collection
Seeding users..
```

And there are no objects in the database. I am using the exact same syntax as I found in a tutorial and can't understand why this is not working. 
Any idea anyone? I guess it is a very stupid error that I just don't see right now. Thanks!

Comment: Can u only run drop database function with try catch the user.remove ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't waiting for `dropDatabase()` and `seedUsers()` to complete before calling `process.exit(0)`.

You need to wrap both of those calls in another `async` method that can wait for their completion.

```
async function doBoth() {
    await dropDatabase();
    await seedUsers();
    process.exit(0);
}

doBoth();
```

However, you probably shouldn't need to call `process.exit(0)`, but that's a separate issue.